# jquery fileupload rails method defaults to put instead of post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, methods, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the jquery-fileupload-rails gem / BlueImp/jquery-file-upload in my rails app.

I'm trying to upload nested resources (documents) associated with my model (transaction) on the /Transactions/:id/edit page which uses form_for @transaction.  This form uses PUT to update the transaction.

Right now, my .fileupload element is a div in a separate form_for at the bottom of the page and with the url set in options to transaction_documents_path.  It uses POST to create the transaction document and works.

I'd like to integrate the .fileupload element div in my edit form and not have two forms.  From the documentation it looks like this is possible.  I'm able to pass the correct transactions_documents_path url to fileupload, but trying to specify the POST method using fileupload's method or type options doesn't seem to override the form_for's PUT method.  When I start the upload, I get a routing error (POST works fine, PUT doesn't.)

Any suggestions for how I can POST rather than PUT?

The .fileupload div:

`<div class="container" id="fileupload" data-type="POST" data-url="<%= transaction_documents_path(@transaction)%>">`

transactions.js.coffee:

```
->
  $("#fileupload").fileupload
      method: 'POST'
      type: 'POST'
      progressall: (e, data) ->
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        $(".progress .bar").css "width", progress + "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably got your problem solved or workarounded by now, but maybe it helps someonelse with the same problem. You probably are specifing your outter form to be a put method (you can look for a hidden input named "_method". You could call it as a post by:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

hope that helps. Also,  its interesting reading some about PUT and POST method. Sometimes PUT is the most appropriated method to be uploading files. Sometimes... :-)